# Firebase function error - UnsupportedMediaTypeError: unsupported content encoding "utf-8"

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to capture data from an API call and keep getting this error

> UnsupportedMediaTypeError: unsupported content encoding "utf-8"

This is my firebase function (nodeJs)

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

exports.input = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.status(200).send('Success');
});
```

Comment: Can you give more context? Where is that error shown? (client or server). Is your function even triggering? Is it local or deployed already? It seems like `admin.initializeApp();` is missing, though without more context I can't tell it's related.

Comment: @maganap Yes the function is triggering and i am getting this error on firebase logs.  I have admin.initializeApp(); on the index.js this function is on a separate file.

Comment: That error is related to the `body-parser` lib used by `express`, which is used by `functions`. Apparently it has something to do with the `Content-Encoding` sent by your client. Can you show what your client is sending? Specially the headers.  
You may also try to google that error but related to `express` and `body-parser`, you'll find more answers since this seems unrelated to `functions`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is how I solved the issue.

In firebase functions this cannot be done, since the header has to be deleted prior to invoking the body parser middleware(this is a workaround). So I had to use Cloud Run for this. I Created a docker image like this.

[image]

### Docker File

```
FROM node:16-alpine 
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json package*.json ./
RUN npm install --only=production
COPY . .
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

### Index

```
const express = require('express');
const Firestore = require('@google-cloud/firestore')
const db = new Firestore();
const app = express();

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    // remove invalid header
    delete req.headers['content-encoding'];
    next();
});
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`SMS in API listening on port ${port}`);
});

app.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    console.log("SMS IN " + req.body.phone_number + " - " + req.body.message);

    await db.collection('sms-in').doc().set({
        phone_number: req.body.phone_number,
        shortcode: req.body.shortcode,
        message: req.body.message,
    });
    res.json('Success');
});

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    res.json('I have nothing to give you.');
})
```

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "smsin",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Description here",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "Author name here",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/firestore": "^5.0.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is here: `res.status(200).send('Success');`
You need to pass json data here is example:

```
res.status(200).send({success: true, data: { key: "value"}});
```